# Operating on character '№'

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-3.x, special-characters

I want to search and replace the character '№' in a string. 
I am not sure if it's actually a single character or two.
How do I do it? What is its unicode?
If it's any help, I am using Python3.

EDIT: The sentence "I am not sure if it's actually a single character or two" kind of deformed my question. I actually wanted to know its unicode so that I could use the code instead of pasting the character in my python script.

Comment: This? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2116/index.htm

Comment: Do you actually have a problem?

Comment: @MisterBhoot Character is character. Some characters may consist of several bytes in some encodings, but that doesn't makes them more than one character.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Your comment answered my question, thank you. If you are willing to convert it into an answer, I will mark it as 'accepted'.

Comment: @jamylak - I couldn't find the code for the character through Google search. This might have a simple solution, but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: @glglgl Erm. Yes. No. Maybe. Which of these is a single character? "é" or "é"? (note: they are different, yet they are the same)

Comment: @glglgl - Thats understood. See my updated question.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Now you got me. :-}

Comment: @MisterBhoot I recognized this one on sight, but for future reference, when I find such a character in text I can copy from, I paste it into BabelMap and get its code point from there. If you cannot use BabelMap you can probably find some alternative, or even some online service.

Comment: `>>> '№'.encode("unicode_escape")`
`b'\\u2116'`

Comment: `3>>hex(ord('№'))`
`'0x2116'`

Comment: @jamylak and Ignacio - Thanks for these handy, permanent solutions. I never will have to post such a silly question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That character is [U+2116 ɴᴜᴍᴇʀᴏ sɪɢɴ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2116/index.htm).

You can just type it directly in your source file, taking care to to specify the source file encoding as per [PEP-236](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Alternatively, you can use either the numeric Unicode escapes, or the more readable [named Unicode escapes](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
>>> 'foo\u2116'
'foo№'
>>> 'foo\N{NUMERO SIGN}'
'foo№'
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add your comment about decompositions to the answer.

Comment: @thg435 I don't think that comment makes sense outside of its context (i.e. where the comment it is replying to exists).

Comment: Up to you, just thought that would clarify OP's and others confusion about "one character or two".

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3 it is always a single character.

```
3>> 'foo№bar'.replace('№', '#')
'foo#bar'
```

Comment: Is that `3>>` supposed to be there (showing you are using Python 3?)?

Comment: @jamylak: Yes. I've set it in my Python 3.x `site.py` so that I can keep my various Python interpreters straight.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - OK. What I want is the encoding for it. I didn't want to copy-paste the character in my script. Martinho's comment did that job. Sorry for my confusing question.

Comment: @MisterBhoot: Characters don't have encodings. Your source code might, but that will be declared at the top of the file (or assumed to be UTF-8).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - OK. Bad wording. So what should I call '\u2116'? character code?